# Pug JS variable passing

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug, pugjs

Hello i have problem with passing variable from gulp to pug and then to the filter. Im passing variable like this.

```
gulp.task('pug-wp', function () {
return gulp.src('src/templates/*.pug')
.pipe(pug({
        pretty: true,
        filters: {
            php: pugPHPFilter
        },
        data: { 
           development: 'php'
        }
    }))
 .pipe(rename({
    extname: ".php"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(outputPath))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

and then i want to use it in

```
:php(type=development)
```

and i have error that says

```
msg: "development" is not constant. All filters are rendered compile-time so                                      filter options must be constants.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the filter is compiled and so expressions are not available in filter attributes, this is not attributes like for tag elements, this all static but you can use this trick:

```
case development
  when 'php'
    :php(type='php')
  when 'foo'
    :php(type='foo')
  when 'bar'
    :php(type='bar')
```

Or if the `developement` variable only depends on the environment, just pass the filter dynamically:

```
switch (developement) {
  case 'php':
    pugPHPFilter.setSomeDefaultOption({ type: 'php' });
    break;
  case 'foo':
    pugPHPFilter.setSomeDefaultOption({ type: 'foo' });
    break;
}
.pipe(pug({
    pretty: true,
    filters: {
        php: pugPHPFilter
    }
}))
```

`setSomeDefaultOption` is an example refer to your `pugPHPFilter` to find the equivalent function.

Comment: Is there any way to pass variable to the strict to the filter ?

Comment: Now, you can't, it's not reliable, it's like expecting pug could see the future. If that would not be needed pug developers would not put this error in the engine.

Comment: Thanks for help i passed this by creating two task with difrrent filters one of the filters is for php and one for the html.

Comment: If the variable only depend on the environment, it's indeed the best way to do it. I edit with your point.